# On hover a tag it disappear

Tags: css

I have an hover function of an element that retrieving a data in the db. It works fine, but when I position the mouse on the result it will disappear. How can I fix this.

my html code:

```
<label class="pending"><a>'+parseFloat(details.pending_aprov).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2})+'</a></label>\
                                        <div class="pending pending'+details.po_no+'" ></div>
```

jquery code:

```
$('label.pending').hover(function(){
                    var po_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.po_id').val();
                    $.getJSON('/dev/api/getpending?po_id=' +po_id, function(results2){
                        $('div.pending'+po_id+'').empty();
                        $.each(results2, function(key, details){
                            $('div.pending'+po_id+'').append('<tr><td><a href="" >CV - '+details.cv_header_id+'</a></td></tr>');
                        })
                    })
                    $('div.pending'+po_id+'').slideToggle();
                })
```

and my css:

```
div.pending{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -2px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #666;
    padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I think we need more HTML context - please copy from the `<tr>`. Also, have you checked the web developer console for errors (e.g. press F12 in Google Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a li tag and put that element inside of li. And adding the css of href.

html:

```
<li class="pend" style="list-style: none;"><label><a href="#">'+parseFloat(details.pending_aprov).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2})+'</a></lable>\
                                        <div class="pending pending'+details.po_no+'" ></div></li>
```

css:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
```